# From mdb Access application to windows application C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've to recode a small access mdb application using c#. What' the best way to re-use and store data now stored in access tables?

Comment: The best way? That would depend on your requirements, which you have not stated.

Comment: I'd suggest SQL Express as a better alternative, but it all depends what you need/want.

Comment: First, thanks to all. I only need to preserve data and relations now stored in mdb file. The main table now hosts about 60,000 records and many relationships. I've to query and filter data once stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just leave it in the Access (JET) MDB format. A C# application can work against that format just fine.

The decision which database to use ultimately depends mostly on your project requirements. The fact that you are using C# isn't really a major consideration in which one you pick.

Comment: Ok, it's the easiest way but I'de like to 'forget' Access :) The application have to store some customers data, create filtered lists (based, for example, on their orders) and send them both fax and email.

Comment: 'forget Access' is hardly a requirement. How many concurrent users, responsiveness through lan access, these are requirements that could lead to a change in database. Don't be fooled, for small/single user applications Access is more than enough and very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll think better

Comment: I agree with Steve. Don't let the Access haters scare you. In the right situation it is a perfectly appropriate solution. The key is understanding the constraints of your project and selecting a platform with a feature-set that meets those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Upsizing Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx) from Microsoft to migrate the database to SQL Server.  If your number of connected users, and database sizing are small enough you can use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) free from Microsoft.

Comment: I didn't know Upsing Wizard, thanks!